# Sort List in Random Alphabetical Order

Tags: c#, list, sorting, compare, comparator

I have a class `Tester`, where the definition is

```
public class Tester
{
     public string Name;
     public int TaskCount;  
     public Tester(string name, int taskCount)
     {
          Name = name;
          TaskCount = taskCount;
     }
}
```

, and I am asked to implement a method to sort a list of `Tester` objects by the ascending order of `TaskCount`.

For example, I have 3 `Tester` objects in the list: `new Tester("A", 1)`, `new Tester("B", 5)`, `new Tester("C", 1)`, and if I just use the default `OrderBy` method to sort them by `TaskCount`, the list would always looks like:

```
A (TaskCount: 1)
C (TaskCount: 1)
B (TaskCount: 5)
```

because in alphabetical order, the letter 'A' always comes before 'C'. Is there a way for me to sort the list in random alphabetical order while it's still in ascending order of `TaskCount`, so there's 50% chance that the result would look like `ACB` and 50% chance be `CAB`? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Random number generator for subsequent ordering after the initial ordering.

```
List<Tester> lt = new List<Tester>();
lt.Add(new Tester("C", 1));
lt.Add(new Tester("B", 5));
lt.Add(new Tester("A", 1));
lt.Add(new Tester("D", 5));

Random r = new Random();
Console.WriteLine(lt.OrderBy(x => x.TaskCount).ThenBy(x => r.Next()));
```

The OrderBy will put the Tester instances into TaskCount order, the ThenBy will randomise those that have the same TaskCount value.

Note - the original ordering of A, C, B was not due to alphabetic order of Name, but order of insertion into the list.